# os.rename() move the directory but does not removed the old one. it worked like copy

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, rename

I'm am running on 'C:\' and copying in 'Y:\', does it matters?

My code:

```
def rename(src, dst):
    try:
        if os.path.exists(dst):
            os.unlink(dst)
        os.renames(src, dst )
        return 0
    except OSError, err:
        print("Rename '%s' to '%s' failed: %s" % (src,dst,os.strerror(err.errno)))
```

Comment: Do you have delete permissions on C:?

Comment: I do have permissions on C:\ and Both src and dst are on Y:\. Also If I use os.remove() it works fine. It means that this is not a permission or location problem.

Answer (score 1):

If different filesystems are involved, you should use `shutil.move(src, dst)`

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html):

> If the destination is on the current filesystem, then os.rename() is used. Otherwise, src is copied (using shutil.copy2()) to dst and then removed.